# how to copy the contents of an excel sheet and paste it in the body of an email.(Not as an attachment) using Python

Tags: python, win32com

I'm writing a python script to send email. Right now it is sending an excel file as an attachment, but instead I want to send the email with the body having the contents of the excel file. Like copying the contents of the excel file with color, formatting etc. and then pasting it in the body of an email.

```py
import win32com.client
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
import pandas as pd 
o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application") 
Msg = o.CreateItem(0)

Msg.To = "abc@gmail.com"

Msg.CC = "xyz@gmail.com" 
Msg.BodyFormat = 2 
Msg.HTMLBody = """
<html>
<body>
   <p>Hello All,<br>
       <br>
       Test HTML mail body from Python
    </p>
  </body>
</html>"""
Msg.Subject = "Automation Test" 
attachment1 = "D:\Demo.xlsx" 
Msg.Attachments.Add(attachment1) 
Msg.Send()
```

This code is working fine but I could not figure out how to add the contents of the excel directly in to the body of an email.

Comment: Would you like the spreadsheet to show up as an html table within the email?

Comment: yes @AnuvratParashar